# How do I target a button using vanilla JS or Jquery to see whether the user has selected it or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the html code for the buttons. The user has 3 options and can only choose one.

```
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
          <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
              <legend>Camera Type:</legend>
              <button class="ui-shadow ui-button" id="btnDSLR">DSLR<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-home"></span></button>
              <button class="ui-shadow ui-button" id="btnPointAndShoot">Point & Shoot<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-home"></span></button>
              <button class="ui-shadow ui-button" id="btnNoCamara">No Camara<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-home"></span></button>
          </fieldset>
        </div>
```

I thought it should be something like this:

```
//Check Camara Type.
    if (document.getElementById("btnDSLR").checked)
    {
      camara += "DSRL";
    }
```

I don't know how to retrieve which option has the user selected.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this.

**jQuery**:

```js
$(".ui-button").on("click",function(e) {
  const $tgt = $(this)
  console.log($tgt.attr("id"),$tgt.text());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
  <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
    <legend>Camera Type:</legend>
    <button class="ui-shadow ui-button" id="btnDSLR">DSLR<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-home"></span></button>
    <button class="ui-shadow ui-button" id="btnPointAndShoot">Point & Shoot<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-home"></span></button>
    <button class="ui-shadow ui-button" id="btnNoCamara">No Camara<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-home"></span></button>
  </fieldset>
  <span id="which"></span>
</div>
```

**Plain/Vanilla JS** needs delegation

```js
document.querySelector("fieldset[data-role=controlgroup]").addEventListener("click",function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.parentNode.classList.contains("ui-button")) tgt = tgt.parentNode; // clicked the span
  if (tgt.classList.contains("ui-button")) {
     console.log(tgt.id,tgt.textContent);
  }
})
```

```html
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
  <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
    <legend>Camera Type:</legend>
    <button class="ui-shadow ui-button" id="btnDSLR">DSLR<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-home"></span></button>
    <button class="ui-shadow ui-button" id="btnPointAndShoot">Point & Shoot<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-home"></span></button>
    <button class="ui-shadow ui-button" id="btnNoCamara">No Camara<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-home"></span></button>
  </fieldset>
  <span id="which"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply get `text` of button as below using `jquery`

```js
$('.ui-button').click(function() {

  console.log( $(this).text() );
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
          <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
              <legend>Camera Type:</legend>
              <button class="ui-shadow ui-button" id="btnDSLR">DSLR<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-home"></span></button>
              <button class="ui-shadow ui-button" id="btnPointAndShoot">Point & Shoot<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-home"></span></button>
              <button class="ui-shadow ui-button" id="btnNoCamara">No Camara<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-home"></span></button>
          </fieldset>
        </div>
```